# Web Animations API это плагин?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, api

С помощью Web Animations API можно делать анимации. Такие же как в jQ только на чистом JS. Объясните эта возможность появилась в ES6 или это нужно подключать плагином как дополнение к стандартному JS?

Comment: Насколько я понял это работает как дополнительные параметры элементов. То есть эту анимацию можно задавать как обычные свойства через CSS, JS и тп. Поддержка зависит от версии браузеров. Эта штука просто удобнее, но в старых браузерах не будет работать, в отличие от анимации на jQ.

Answer (score 2):

Это не плагин. И не стандартная возможность... *пока что*.
Сейчас данный API экспериментальный, он в стадии черновика и на пути к стандарту.

В современных браузерах уже реализована поддержка. И хотя она еще не полная - побаловаться уже можно, если есть желание.

*Имхо: сейчас в любом случае лучше держаться CSS-анимаций... они не только лучше поддерживаются, но и банально удобнее.*
<sup>*jQuery? Не, не слышал. Но звучит как что-то устаревшее))*</sup>

---

Пример использования метода `animate()` из данного API:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('test'), 
    chrs = el.textContent.split(''), 
    html = ''; 
for (let i in chrs)
  html += (chrs[i] === 'о') ? '<span>о</span> ' : chrs[i]; 
el.innerHTML = html; 

let os = el.querySelectorAll('span'); 
for (let o of os) 
  o.animate({
    transform: [
      'scaleX(1.2)', 
      'translateY(-0.5em) scale(1, 1.2)', 
      'translateY(-0.7em) scale(1.5, 0.5)'
    ]},
    { duration: 200, ease: 'ease-out', iterations: Infinity, direction: 'alternate' }
  ); 

el.animate([
    { offset: 0, transform: 'scaleY(0)', left: '0', top: '1em', color: '#000' },
    { transform: 'scaleY(0)', offset: 0.10 },
    { transform: 'none',      offset: 0.15, ease: 'ease-in' }, {
      transform: 'none', left: '0', top: '1em', 
      offset: 0.35
    }, {
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', 
      left: '50vw', top: '50vh', 
      offset: 0.375, ease: 'ease-out'
    }, {
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', 
      left: '50vw', color: '#f00',
      offset: 0.50
    }, {
      transform: 'rotateY(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%)', 
      left: 'calc(50vw - 210px)', color: '#f00', 
      offset: 0.55
    }, {
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', left: '50vw', 
      offset: 0.60
    }, {
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', 
      left: '50vw', top: '50vh', color: '#07f', 
      offset: 0.75
    }, {
      transform: 'none', left: '0', top: '1em', 
      offset: 0.775, ease: 'ease-out'
    },
    { transform: 'none',      offset: 0.85}, 
    { transform: 'scaleY(0)', offset: 0.90},
    { offset: 1, transform: 'scaleY(0)', left: '0', top: '1em', color: '#000' }
  ], 
  { duration: 12000, iterations: Infinity}
);
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 1em; 
  width: 420px; text-align: center; 
  font: 18px monospace; 
}
#test > span { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<span id="test">Подключать что-либо - совсем не нужно.</span>
```